# How to set timeout duration in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

Hi Guys i am getting this timeout error when i try to upload files that are stored in an array to an SFTP site. I have included the error message as well as my code. And is they a way i can upload all my files loaded in the array at once? Can you please assist.

Renci.SshNet.Common.SshOperationTimeoutException: Session operation has timed out
at Renci.SshNet.Session.WaitOnHandle(WaitHandle waitHandle, TimeSpan timeout)
at Renci.SshNet.Session.WaitOnHandle(WaitHandle waitHandle)

```
namespace SFTP_Upload
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Getting Configuration File Ready");

            string password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["password"];
            string username = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["username"];
            string Host_Name = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Host_Name"];
            string Port = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Port"];
            string Manifest_Path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Manifest_Path"];
            string PayslipZip_Path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PayslipZip_Path"];
            string Server_Path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Server_Path"];

            string[] Manifest_files =
            Directory.GetFiles(Manifest_Path, "*.csv", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

            string[] Zip_Files =
            Directory.GetFiles(Manifest_Path, "*.zip", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

            Console.WriteLine("Uploading Files To: " + Host_Name);

            //upload file to sftp server

            using (SftpClient client = new SftpClient(new PasswordConnectionInfo(Host_Name, username, password)))
            {
                client.Connect();

                foreach (string s in Manifest_files)
                {
                    using Stream stream = File.OpenRead(s);
                    client.UploadFile(stream, @Server_Path + Path.GetFileName(s));
                }

                foreach (string j in Zip_Files)
                {
                    using Stream stream = File.OpenRead(j);
                    client.UploadFile(stream, @Server_Path + Path.GetFileName(j));
                }
                client.Disconnect();
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Files Uploaded Successfully to: " + Host_Name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use CommandTimeOut methode @james

Comment: more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout

Comment: and in linq: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.linq.datacontext.commandtimeout?view=netframework-4.8